# How to write an Exception to a text file

Tags: java

```
import java.io.*;
class FileWrite 
{
 public static void main(String args[])
  {
  try{
  // Create file 
  FileWriter fstream = new FileWriter("out.txt");
  BufferedWriter out = new BufferedWriter(fstream);
  out.write("Hello Java");
  //Close the output stream
  out.close();
  }catch (Exception e){//Catch exception if any
     // CAN I WRITE THE EXCEPTION TO THE TEXT FILE
   }
  }
}
```

I am writing text to a file. Can i write the exception thrown in the `catch` block to the `out.txt` file ?

Comment: Have you considered using logging to handle this. Something like log4j or logback?

Comment: Yes, you can. But the problem is if you actually catch an exception there it's likely you'll just encounter the same exception when you try to write it to the text file in your catch block.

Comment: @jschoen Can i use log4j for a console based application ?

Comment: @user1315906, I suppose you can.

Comment: if you still want to do it the way you thought of initially, you could possibly try writing to a different file other than out.txt because as @ZacharyYates already noted, the exception most likely will occur again if you try writing to out.txt in your catch block.

Comment: You should be able to yes. I believe you would want [ConsoleAppender](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/apidocs/org/apache/log4j/ConsoleAppender.html) for that. You can take a look at [Log4j Multiple Appender Example](http://www.dzone.com/tutorials/java/log4j/log4j-example-multiple-appender.html) to see how to set it up to log to both a file and the console.

Answer (score 2):

You should not and probably could not write the exception to the file, whose writer may have caused the error. 
But you can try using a logger, like log4j, as already suggested and in your catch block. You could simply add something as:

```
   private static final Category log = Category.getInstance(MyClass.class.getName());
   ...
   catch (Exception e) {
    logger.log(e.getMessage());
   }
```

Learn more about logging [here](http://www.techrepublic.com/article/add-logging-to-your-java-applications/1027665) or in [this post](http://javawords.com/2008/01/08/how-to-use-log4j-logging-api/).
Also check out the [log4j docs](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/manual.html).

Comment: There is also the built-in "java.util.logging".

Comment: log4j or any other logging facility will just add timing and other infos to the output file - if that code fall on the catch cause you don't have permission to write on the filesystem (example), the logger will equally fail. You mentioned it is a command-line app., so you can start it piping the output (std.out) to a file:
java thApp > errors.txt

Comment: If it's a console application, though not nice, you could simply use System.err.println(e.getStackTrace()) (hoping your standard error output is not redirected to something else).

Answer (score 0):

Call the following method in `catch` block and pass the object. That will do your work:

```
 public static void writeException(Exception e) {
     try {
        FileWriter fs = new FileWriter("out.txt", true);
        BufferedWriter out = new BufferedWriter(fs);
        PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(out, true);
        e.printStackTrace(pw);
     }
     catch (Exception ie) {
        throw new RuntimeException("Could not write Exception to file", ie);
     }
  }
```

As Ex.

```
try{
   new NullPointerException();
}
catch(Exception e){
   writeException(e);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can write the exception to a text file. But if the exception happened in the line where you are creating the FileWriter or BufferedWriter, then you wont be able to use this object based on the state of these objects. Also you need to declare the instance of these objects outside the try block to enable visibility.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use the same `out` variable from the `try` block to write to `out.txt`, since the exception could have been thrown anywhere in the `try` block.  This means that in the `catch` block `out` might not be initialized, or attempting to write using it will cause the same exception you are current catching.

You could attempt to open the file again in the `catch` block to write the exception, but since opening and writing to the same file has just failed it is unlikely that this will work.

Answer (score 0):

```
//breaking code
} catch (Exception e) {
    File f = new File("/tmp/someFileYouCanActuallyWriteOn.txt");
    if (!f.exists())
         f.createNewFile();
    e.printStackTrace(new PrintStream(f));
}
```

But consider the comment from [zachary-yates](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8360/zachary-yates). Also, catching 'Exception' and not the specific type is discouraged - but if you really want to catch everything, catch Throwabble